# Problemas em apagar todos os dados de um funcionario

Tags: c

Após criação do create e do read tenho vindo a ter problemas o no código relativo ao update e ao delete, mas atualmente tenho me focado mais no delete e não estou a conseguir fazer com que apague o funcionário na totalidade.

Objetivo: o utilizador insere o ID do funcionário e ele apaga todos os dados relativos ao funcionário.

Infelizmente o resultado está longe de ser o pedido aqui fica o código.

`

```
FILE *fRead, *fWrite;

char c;
int Delete_Id, temp = 1;

fRead = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
c = getc(fRead);

while (c != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
    c = getc(fRead);
}

rewind(fRead);

printf("\nDelete Staff with ID: ");
scanf("%d", &Delete_Id);

Delete_Id = Delete_Id + 1;

fWrite = fopen("temporary.tmp", "w");
c = getc(fRead);

while (c != EOF) {
    c = getc(fRead);
    if (c == '\n')
        temp++;
    if (temp != Delete_Id) {
        putc(c, fWrite);
    }
}

fclose(fRead);
fclose(fWrite);

remove(FILENAME);

rename("temporary.tmp", FILENAME);
printf("\nThe contents of file after being modified are as follows:\n");

fRead = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
c = getc(fRead);
while (c != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
    c = getc(fRead);
}
fclose(fRead)
```

O resultado do output[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado do ficheiro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que entendi em vez de apagar os dados relativos ao funcionario ele apenas elimina conforme a linha pedida e não o id dele, fora isso "come" as primeiras letras apresentadas no txt e acrescenta um ý no fim do ficheiro.

**variaveis do funcionario**

```
struct funcionario {
    
    int codigo1[100], idade[100], numero_telefone[100], numero_dependentes[100];
    char nome[100], estado_civil[100];

};

struct funcionario e;
```

Alguem poderia ajudar?? Já sao diversos dias a tentar solucionar este problema verificando diversos exemplos.

Answer (score -3):

Pretende usar um ficheiro para cada funcionario?

Se vai usar em forma de tabela, deveria ponderar guardar a informação num formato mais convencional como CSV, JSON ou XML. Por uma questão de simplicidade eu escolheria CSV.

Para remover registos da lista, eu nao tentaria apagar os dados desse funcionario, mas sim, acrescentar um atributo REMOVIDO e alterar o estado apenas desse atributo.